# How do I insert into a join table with Entity Framework 4.1 when change tracking is turned off?

Tags: performance, entity-framework-4.1

**Background:**
I am working on a project where I am importing a bunch of data from a CSV file into a database using the .NET Entity Framework (v4.1).  During the import I expect to see a lot of "errors" (i.e. lookup failures), possibly multiple per row, and these need to be able to be resolved later by an administrator through a manual process.  Many of the errors are the same from row to row (i.e. same column, same data value and same error code, but different rows), so to make it easier for the administrator to resolve them, I lump them together.  In other words, when inserting row data, if I encounter an error that has been seen before on a different row, I link the new row to that error instead of inserting a new one.  I am using a hash table to do this lookup quickly.

My model looks like this:

- Each file is represented by an **ImportFile** object
- Each ImportFile has a collection of **ImportErrors** (one to many)
- Each ImportFile also has a collection of **DataRows** (one to many)
- There is a many-to-many relationship between DataRows and ImportErrors such that each
  has a collection of the other.

**My conundrum:** 
I've got the code working and inserting all of this data in the database properly, but when the import file starts getting above say a few hundred rows, the performance is horrendous.  I'm sure ths is because of all the change tracking that is done by the Entity Framework behind the scenes.  I'd like to turn off change tracking to improve performance, but if I do that, I don't see a way to get the Entity Framework to insert the join records between the DataRows and the ImportErrors.  As I'm sure you know, the Entity Framework does not generate an entity to represent the join; instead it looks at whether you have added items to the respective collections on the joined entities.

So, does anyone know a way around this?  Is there a way to tell the entity framework explicitly to insert a join record?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Currently I am using a single DbContext for the entire import.  I create all the objects, adding them to the context as I go, and I then do a single SaveChanges() at the end.

**Other things I've tried:**

- Calling SaveChanges() more frequently (once per row) - this made things even slower
- Attempting to use a new DbContext for each DataRow - in this case the entity framework complained that "the relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."  The error did not say which specific objects it was trying to relate at the time.  I tried this multiple ways and I can't seem to make the EF happy no matter what I do with this approach.

**Other approaches I'm considering but haven't tried yet:**

- Creating a way to break the import file into small 100-row chunks and then processing each chunk as its own file (for each chunk I'd have to to reload all my lookup data and the errors from previous chunks so they're all in the same context)
- Creating stored procs to facilitate the inserts instead (kind of goes against the grain of using the EF in the first place, but I'll do it if there's no other way)

Many thanks in advance for your insights.
-Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to deal with the problem: I created an explicit entity for the join record in my model.  So now there is an object **DataRowImportError** which has a one-to-many relationship with both DataRow and ImportError, while DataRow and ImportError no longer have a direct relationship between them.  This allows me to insert (or delete) the join records directly, which in turn allows me to turn off change tracking during the import and greatly improve performance.  The only downside is the model isn't quite as "friendly" to work with, but hey, that's the cost of business sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm sure ths is because of all the change tracking that is done by the
>   Entity Framework behind the scenes.

I am not sure. This might be true if your change tracking is snapshot based, i.e. you are using POCOs (you do with EF 4.1) and don't work with change tracking proxies. But change tracking by proxies is actually very fast (up to factor 50 faster than snapshot based change tracking by my own experience with a similar problem).

But enabling change tracking proxies has the strict requirement that **all** your model properties must be `virtual`, not only the navigation properties, also the scalar properties. If this is the case EF will enable change tracking proxies by default. You can turn it off in other situations where you don't need or want them:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Having all properties `virtual` will also enable lazy loading by default. If you don't want this you can disable it:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Disclaimer: My experience with proxies to improve the performance is very good, but I've never used it with a model with a many-to-many relationship, so I don't know if proxies will have the same effect on performance in such a model.

Another solution you could test is to disable automatic change tracking:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

This can also improve the performance. But you have to be careful then to call `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` manually at the proper points to not introduce bugs into your code.

Other options than that would be Stored Procedures (as you said) or using direct SQL. EF doesn't offer another way to insert data into the join table than using the change tracking mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about proxy tracking; I did not know that was an option. I do have lazy loading turned off already (mainly to ensure I'm not degrading performance even more by loading things I don't need at times I least expect). I have also tried disabling change tracking; that is what led to my question in the first place (the join records don't get inserted when I do this).